# Identify valid compressed values for DECOMPRESS function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column containing compressed values, which can be decompressed using the following:

```
CAST(DECOMPRESS(CAST(content AS VARBINARY(max))) AS VARCHAR(MAX))
```

However, a small number of rows return the error below. I believe some corrupted data or otherwise inappropriate values were inserted at some point.

> Uncompressed or corrupted data passed as argument to DECOMPRESS builtin.

How can I query to identify which rows have valid compressed content and which would trigger this error?

Is there a better method than looping through with a TRY/CATCH?

Comment: Tricky...you can't use a function as functions cannot contain TRY CATCH blocks. Does the compressed data contain sensitive information?

Comment: The documentation for [COMPRESS() and DECOMPRESS()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/compress-transact-sql) states that the GZIP algorithm is used. The Wikipedia [GZIP article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip) states that the compressed data will start with "a 10-byte header, containing a magic number (1f 8b) [and] the compression method (08 for DEFLATE)". Thus, you can check that the first two bytes equal 1f 8b as a first line of defense. (This might not be future proof, since Microsoft could change the implementation in future versions.)

Comment: @Alex Yes it is sensitive data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77910355/identify-valid-compressed-values-for-decompress-function#comment137353570_77910355) from [@T N](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12637193/t-n) as I'm satisfied with this solution:

The documentation for [COMPRESS() and DECOMPRESS()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/compress-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) states that the GZIP algorithm is used. The Wikipedia [GZIP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip) article states that the compressed data will start with "a 10-byte header, containing a magic number (1f 8b) [and] the compression method (08 for DEFLATE)". Thus, you can check that the first two bytes equal 1f 8b as a first line of defense. (This might not be future proof, since Microsoft could change the implementation in future versions.)

Comment: This is how my SQL looks:
`select
 case when substring(binContent, 1, 2) = 0x1f8b
  then cast(decompress(binContent) as varbinary(max))
  else binContent
 end as binContent
from
 tblFileContent`

Answer (score 1):

Sample logic to test if a column is utilizing column compression (compress/decompress)

Checks if field was compressed:

```
where cast([F1] as varbinary(2)) = cast(0x1F8B as varbinary(2))
```

Checks if field is not compressed:

```
where cast([F1] as varbinary(2)) = cast(0x2F00 as varbinary(2))
```